# pass parameterized constructor as method reference

Tags: java, java-8

Is it possible to pass parameterized constructor as method reference to `map`?

I've got a facility in my code that looks like this

```
items.stream()
        .map(it -> new LightItem(item.getId(), item.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My `items` list constains several `Item` objects

```
Item
   id, name, reference, key...
```

whereas `LightItem` has only two fields

```
LightItem
    id, name
```

It would be good if it was possible to do something like this

```
items.stream().map(LightItem::new).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's only one way to use constructor here, you have to add a new constructor to `LightItem` class:

```
public LightItem(Item item) {
    this.id = item.getId();
    this.name = item.getName();
}
```

This will allow you to use the code you wrote:

```
items.stream().map(LightItem::new).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

If you really don't want to add a new constructor to `LightItem`, there's way around:

```
class MyClass {

    public List<LightItem> someMethod() {
        return items.stream()
            .map(MyClass::buildLightItem)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static LightItem buildLightItem(Item item) {
        return new LightItem(item.getId(), item.getName());
    }

}
```